# Topology on rational intervals

Tags: general-topology, rational-numbers

Corrected question: I want to find a topology based on the set of all Dedekind Cuts without using the notion of real numbers. Because of the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ I cannot define a bijection from the Cuts to the set of rational numbers. Is there a way to construct such a topology?

Comment: What about hereditary topology from real numbers? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_property

Comment: The set is in bijection with ${\mathbb Q}$, why about the usual topology of ${\mathbb Q}$?

Comment: Can you define the bijection? I don't see it

Comment: @Averroes2 Well, simply the mapping $a \mapsto (-\infty, a)$.

Comment: What don't you see @Averroes2 ? $a\mapsto(-\infty,a)$ is the canonical bijection . The intervals , then , are just symbols which represent the rational number $a$ . Now you can just define the topology to be such that the canonical bijection is a homeomorphism.

Comment: The set of all Dedekind cuts is not the set of intervals $(-\infty, a)$ with $a\in {\mathbb Q}$

Comment: Thanks, have corrected the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let ${\cal D}$ be the set of all Dedekind cuts of ${\mathbb Q}$, that is to say the set of all non empty proper subsets $A\subsetneq {\mathbb Q}$ downward closed and without upper bound. For $0 < r \in {\mathbb Q}$, define the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $A$ as the set of all $A'\in {\mathcal D}$ such that $A-r \subsetneq A'\subsetneq A+r$. The topology generated by these open balls in ${\mathcal D}$ is the topology of ${\mathbb R}$, defined without using real numbers.

A subset $U\subset {\mathcal D}$ is **open** in this topology **if and only if** for every $A\in U$, there exists $r\in {\mathbb Q}$ such that $r > 0$ and $B(A, r)\subset U$.

Comment: Thank you. This means that your Topology is nothing else but the set $\mathcal{D}$ itself? Is this right? But how can $\mathcal{D}$ be itself an open set?

Comment: A topology on a set ${\mathcal D}$ is a subset of $T\subset {\mathcal P}({\mathcal D})$ which elements are exactly the open sets of that topology. The set ${\mathcal D}$ is itself an open set. This is included in the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology) of a topology. Here the topology is the smallest topology containing the open balls defined above.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=\{A\subseteq\mathbb Q\text{ closed}:b<a\in A\Rightarrow b\in A\}\setminus\{\emptyset,\mathbb Q\}$ be the set of Dedekind cuts.

Say a subset $U\subseteq R$ is open if for each $A\in U$, there exist rational numbers $p<q$ with $(-\infty,p]\subsetneq B\subsetneq(-\infty, q] \Rightarrow B\in U$. Equivalently, a rational $r\in B$ with $p<r<q$ witnesses $B\in U$.